# Analysis proof.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a task:

> Prove that $||z|−|w||≤|z|+|w|$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb C$.

What I did:

Represent $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$.
We will have: $|a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2| \leq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$
Do you think that it is the right strategy to prove it? And if yes, do you have any ideas about how to prove the last line that it is always true? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse triangle inequality states that $\bigg| |x| - |y| \bigg| \leq |x-y|$ and is valid in any normed space. Combining this with the ordinary triangle inequality (also valid in any normed space) we have $|x-y| \leq |x| + |y|$

Both of these questions have surely been asked before on this site, under those names, so if you can't fill in the steps from here, you could look for those keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Use the triangle inequality:
$$||z| - |w|| \le ||z|| + ||w|| = |z| + |w|.$$

Answer (score 1):

This exercise in fact has nothing to do with $\mathbb C$, as $|z|$ and $|w|$ are non-negative reals !

Then

$$a-b\le a+b\land b-a\le a+b$$ because

$$-b\le b\land -a\le a.$$

---

Equality occurs with $|z|=0\lor|w|=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the inequality directly by squaring:

\begin{eqnarray*} 
 ||z|−|w|| & ≤ & |z|+|w| \\
&  \Leftrightarrow & \\
||z|-|w||^2 & \leq & (|z| + |w|)^2 \\
&  \Leftrightarrow & \\
|z|^2 + |w|^2 - 2|z||w| & \leq & |z|^2 + |w|^2+ 2|z||w| \\
&  \Leftrightarrow & \\
0 & \leq & |z||w|
\end{eqnarray*}

The last inequality is obviously true.